# Get vertices of image?

Tags: java, math, graphics

I'm working with sprite art, and I need to generate a polygon (array of vertices) for a collision detector.

I have a `getPixel(x, y)` method I can use to get the color of a pixel. I don't need any fancy color detection or anything, just solid pixels and transparent pixels. Here's what I started before my brain started to melt:

```
boolean[] hasColor = new boolean[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    int row;
    row = i % width;
    if ((pixmap.getPixel(i, row) != 0) || (pixmap.getPixel(row, i) != -256)) {
        hasColor[i] = true;
    } else {
        hasColor[i] = false;
    }
}
```

That should keep track of what pixels are empty, and what aren't. But I don't know where I should go from here.

Is there an algorithm or something I can use to help? Can someone provide input?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

What you have is raster artwork.

What you need is a vector outline.

Converting from vector to raster is easy, raster to vector, not so much.

Here is one possible workflow:

1. Convert your artwork into a black-and-white image (like your pixel color present/not-present matrix).
2. Use Adobe Illustrator's "Live Trace" feature to vectorize this image.
3. Export the outline polygon into a format that you can read back easily.
4. Use this as your input for the collision detection.

Here's another approach:

A) Assume that the outline looks like a hexagon, like this:

```
       *****
      *     *
     *       *
    *         *
     *       *
      *     *
       *****
```

B) Define "fit" as the goodness of an outline, calculated by checking what percentage of the pixels are inside the hexagon (does not have to be the regular-shaped figure shown above).
C) Change the positions of the vertices, until you find an optimum fit (or until you get tired).

Step (C) is, of course, the hardest one. Plus, if your sprite needs more vertices, you may need to start out with an octagon/n-gon instead.